# Using Out-Printer within a script

Tags: powershell, pdf, printing

So the mentioned method is from here (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/6Print/0.1.0/Content/Out-Printer.ps1)

I have been stuggeling with this, because while the method works fine while in command-prompt, it will fail in a script, whatever i do.

So my input is a .tif image and i want to print a pdf. So in the shell i would try something like

```
>cd desktop
>. .\out-printer
>Out-Printer -ImagePath $env:userprofile\desktop\test.tif -PrinterName 'Microsoft Print to PDF' -PrintFileName $env:userprofile\Desktop\test.pdf -LandScape -PaperSize a4
```

Which would be fine. But lets say i add the function 'test' to the bottom or top of 'Out-File.ps1' which looks like this right now:

```
function test(){
Out-Printer -ImagePath $env:userprofile\desktop\test.tif -PrinterName 'Microsoft Print to PDF' -PrintFileName $env:userprofile\Desktop\test.pdf -LandScape -PaperSize a4
}
```

and execute with
`> . '.\Out-Printer.ps1'; Test`

This givs me an error starting with:

> New-Object : Der Typ [System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection] kann nicht gefunden werden. Stellen Sie sicher,
>   dass die Assembly, die diesen Typ enthält, geladen wird.
>   In C:\Users\erdmannr\desktop\Out-Printer.ps1:78 Zeichen:27
>   + ... lledFonts = New-Object -TypeName "System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCo ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

This goes on for a while, and most errors are about [System.Drawing.*]

Please help, i just want to print a .tif to a *.pdf =)

Comment: Try running `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing` before `Out-Printer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `Out-Printer` does not automatically loads some dependencies.

You can can load the `System.Drawing.dll` assembly manually with:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
```

Comment: THIIS WORKS!! I will have to read up on this but thank you soooo much.